# Изменить container на container-fluid

Tags: bootstrap, responsive

Можно ли например на больших экранах использовать container, а при уменьшении до маленьких удалить отступы, тоесть использовать container-fliud? Может есть другой грамотный способ? Спасибо за любую информацию.

Comment: А что мешает использовать просто container? Отступы (левый-правый) задаются в колонках, не в контейнере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажу основных **2 способа** которых я использую.

```
$(window).resize(function(e){
     if ($(window).width() < 1196) { //1169
        $(".wrapper > .container").removeClass("container").addClass("container-fluid");
    }
    else if($(window).width() > 1196) { // 1169
        $(".wrapper > .container-fluid").removeClass("container-fluid").addClass("container");
    }
});
```

При уменьшении окна в браузере через `jQuery`

Также основной способ используя чистый `javascript` рекoмендую использовать их обоих

```
var windowsSize=function(){

        let w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

        if (w < 1196) {
            (".wrapper > .container").removeClass("container").addClass("container-fluid");

        }
        else if (w > 1196) {
            (".wrapper > .container-fluid").removeClass("container-fluid").addClass("container");

 }; 
windowSize();
```

**Ключевой момент** чтобы знать какой `container` взять я поставил перед ними `wrapper` чтобы взять самый первый который находятся  внути основного блока

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то что мне нужно!

Comment: @AndreiKazmirovich рад помочь =)